# necessary condition to fix weird lemma's?

Tags: python, nltk, text-analysis, lemmatization

(**Executed in jupyter notbook**) I'm applying lemmatization on documents that I've tokenised and I can't help but notice that the word "us" gets lemmatized to "u" every time which wouldn't make sense from a clarity point of view and could possibly lead people to understand it as something else. Am I missing out a condition for my pos function? How could I fix this problem?

**Defining the function**

```
from nltk import pos_tag

def penn2wordNet(treebank_tags):
    wordNet_tag = {'NN':'n', 'JJ':'a',
                  'VB':'v', 'RB':'r'}
    try:
        return wordNet_tag[penntag[:2]]
    except:
        return 'n'
paired_tags = []
for doc in wordTokens:
    paired_tags.append(pos_tag(doc))
    print(paired_tags)
```

[image: snippet output of the code above]

**Lemmatizing the tokens**

```
    from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

print(wordTokens[1])
lemmatized_wordTokens = []
for index in range(len(paired_tags)):
    lemmatized_wordTokens.append(([wnl.lemmatize(word, pos=penn2wordNet(tag)) for word, tag in paired_tags[index]]))
print(lemmatized_wordTokens[1])
```

[image: output after lemmatization showing before and after]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `penn2wordNet` function assigns the noun POS tag to "us" although `pos_tag(['us'])` returns `[('us', 'PRP')]`. This makes `WordNetLemmatizer` to treat "us" as a noun. You have to add an additional condition to handle personal pronouns.

Comment: Thanks my dude! Hard coding a condition worked just fine!